# How to integrate $\int \frac{e^x \cos x}{\tan x+\operatorname{sec}x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

How to integrate:

$$\int \frac{e^x \cos x}{\tan x+\operatorname{sec}x}dx$$

I don't really have a clue? Do I need to simplify it first somehow?

Comment: Try multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\tan(x)-\sec(x)$.  Then, break up the integral and use parts twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: show that $$\frac{e^x\cos(x)}{\tan(x)+sec(x)}=\frac{e^x\cos(x)^2}{1+\sin(x)}$$ and multiply numerator and denominator in the last term by $1-\sin(x)$ and then integrate by parts

Comment: oh wait I think it's better to say $cos^2x = 1-sin^2x$ then cancel after factorising?

Comment: @StephanCasey. You are correct. This will let you with $e^x (1-\sin (x))$ which will be easy to integrate by parts twice.

Comment: i think this is the same like i proposedf